# String replace of a list from a list in R

Tags: r, string

I have a list and I want to replace the occurrence of one with count below

```
str_list <- c("2","1","2","1")
str_replace_all(str_list,"1",c("1:once","1:twice"))
```

gives output

```
[1] "2"       "1:twice" "2"       "1:twice"
```

but it should give

```
[1] "2"       "1:once" "2"       "1:twice"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex here since this is an exact match. Try :

```
str_list[str_list == "1"] <- c("1:once","1:twice")
str_list
#[1] "2"       "1:once"  "2"       "1:twice"
```

The only precaution you need to take is make sure number of `"1"`s is same as number of replacement (`c("1:once","1:twice")`) otherwise it might give you unexpected results.